# Backup script Debian \r': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I'm trying to make a script to back-up my MariaDB SQL. When I try to archive the folder (after Maria Backup created them) I use the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash 

TIME=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
tar cvf "/home/pi/backupsql/MariaDB-$TIME.tar.gz" "/home/pi/backupsql/xtrabackup_backupfiles/"
```

If I put anything else below the `tar` line, I get:

```
2.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Linux uses `LF`, not `CRLF` or `CR`. Use `dos2unix <my backup script>`.

Comment: Try this `tar -czvf /home/pi/backupsql/MariaDB-$TIME.tar.gz /home/pi/backupsql/xtrabackup_backupfiles/`

Comment: As mentioned by @jww the reason is wrong line endings. Aside from that, some tips on how to make your script better: use `set -eu` to make the script fail on the first failing command and to error out on undefined variables. Do not quote paths or they might be taken for single file names by some programs. Fully define variables, especially within strings. Write `.../MariaDB-${TIME}.tar.gz` with the `TIME` in curly brackets.

Comment: Can use `od -c script.sh` to dump the characters in the file (i.e. trailing `\r\n` characters).